# Typeclass constraints with higher kinded types

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write an `Eq` instance for an `EitherT` newtype given by:

```
newtype EitherT e m a = EitherT { runEitherT :: m (Either e a) }
```

I assumed the following `Eq` instance would work:

```
instance (Eq e, Eq a, Eq m) => Eq (EitherT e m a) where
  a == b = (runEitherT a) == (runEitherT b)
```

However, I'm seeing an error:

```
Expected kind '* -> *', but 'm' has kind '*'
```

What I'm reading from that error is that my typeclass constraint `( ... Eq m) => ...` is confusing the compiler into thinking that I believe `m` to be of kind `*`, when my newtype declaration for `EitherT` expects it to be of kind `* -> *`.

I'm wondering what I need to do, to declare that I want an `Eq` instance for some higher kinded type `m` to implement `Eq` for my `EitherT` newtype.

**Edit:** As pointed out by @AlexisKing, I can get this to work with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecideableInstances #-}
instance (Eq (m (Either e a))) => Eq (EitherT e m a) where
  a == b = (runEitherT a) == (runEitherT b)
```

However, it seems strange to me to that a language extension is required to write this `Eq` instance. Is there no other way to express such a typeclass constraint in vanilla Haskell? If not, why?

Comment: You probably want `Eq (m b)`, not `Eq m`. For what it’s worth, though, I think you could just have GHC derive this class for you, and it would figure out the necessary constraints.

Comment: @AlexisKing That gives a different error `Variable 'b' occurs more often in the constraint 'Eq (m b)' than in the instance head`. Also, ghc will not derive this typeclass for me, I'm not entirely sure why though.

Comment: You can turn on `StandaloneDeriving` and `UndecidableInstances` and write `deriving instance Eq (m (Either e a)) => Eq (EitherT e m a)`. Alternatively, you can write the instance you currently have, but replace all your constraints with `Eq (m (Either e a))`.

Comment: Thanks for the help @AlexisKing. I'd like to try to write this `Eq` instance myself, if only to understand what's going on. However, using `Eq (m (Either e a))` in the typeclass constraint produces a warning and asks me to turn on `UndecidableInstances`. Is it really not possible to write this instance without UndecidableInstances? If so, why? I'm going to edit my question to include this.

Comment: `UndecidableInstances` is safe. It allows type class resolution to be recursive in non-total ways. The worst thing that happens is the _compiler_  gets stuck in a recursive loop. If the compiler terminates the resulting code is still safe. It's an extension because a compiler is expected to terminate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for `Eq1` which is in [`Data.Functor.Classes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Classes.html) since base 4.9.0.0. Before that it was in one of the `-extras` packages or `transformers`? (it's [in transformers now since 0.4.0.0](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Classes.html))

`Eq1 f` says that you can compare `f`s as long as you have a way to compare their contents

```
class Eq1 f where
    liftEq :: (a -> b -> Bool) -> f a -> f b -> Bool
```

In your case you'd use it like

```
instance (Eq e, Eq1 m) => Eq1 (EitherT e m) where
   liftEq f a b = liftEq (liftEq f) (runEitherT a) (runEitherT b)
```

The `liftEq f` is to use the existing `Eq1` instance for `Either`.

And can define an `Eq` instance as

```
instance (Eq e, Eq a, Eq1 m) => Eq (EitherT e m a) where
   (==) = liftEq (==)
```

---

The old `Eq1` was

```
class Eq1 f where
    eq1 :: (Eq a) => f a -> f a -> Bool
```

In your case you'd use it like

```
instance (Eq e, Eq1 m) => Eq1 (EitherT e m) where
   eq1 a b = eq1 (runEitherT a) (runEitherT b)

instance (Eq e, Eq a, Eq1 m) => Eq1 (EitherT e m) where
   a == b = eq1 (runEitherT a) (runEitherT b)
```

Comment: `Eq1` is only ever necessary if you want to write “standard” Haskell, which I would never recommend. Haskell without extensions is not a very useful language.

Comment: According to https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11135 , `Eq1` has been moved to base, and had its definition changed, see: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Classes.html#t:Eq1 . The `Eq1` in `base` has minimal definition of `liftEq :: (a -> b -> Bool) -> f a -> f b -> Bool`. I'm finding it significantly harder to write an implementation of `liftEq` than for than `eq1`.

Comment: @Wilduck That's a much better definition for `Eq1`, I'll update the answer.

Comment: I've learned a lot today Cirdec and @AlexisKing. Thank you both!

Comment: Of note for the first definition is that `Either` already has an instance of `Eq1`: `Eq a => Eq1 (Either a)`, which allows the `liftEq (liftEq f)`.

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth noting that this instance already exists in current versions of the `either` package (though not the old `EitherT` package, which is considered obsolete):

```
instance Eq (m (Either e a)) => Eq (EitherT e m a) where
  (==) = (==) on runEitherT
```

Of course, as @Alexis King has noted, it requires `UndecidableInstances`, but the `either` package is authored by Edward Kmett, a notorious dilettante and amateur who can't write proper Haskell98 like us *real* programmers.  ;)